# What bounds does an approximate identity give in terms of supremum's of functions?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

What bounds does an approximate identity give: $f_{\epsilon} = \int f(x-y)\frac{1}{\epsilon}\phi(\frac{y}{\epsilon})dy$ for the following inequalities?

$\sup_{x}|f_{\epsilon}(x)|\leq ?\sup_{x}|f(x)|$

$\sup_{x}|f_{\epsilon}'(x)|\leq ?\sup_{x}|f(x)|$

$\sup_{x}|f_{\epsilon}''(x)|\leq ?\sup_{x}|f(x)|$

I think the first one is bounded by $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and then you just continually take derivatives because the function $\phi$ is smooth but I'm pretty apprehensive that it is that simple.

Comment: There is a better bound for the first one which you can see by computing the integral $\phi(y/\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Funktorality computing the first integral just gives you 1 does it not? considering it is a approximate identity by definition it needs to be 1 (by first integral i mean $\int\phi(\frac{y}{\epsilon})dy$

Comment: It should give $\epsilon$ by change of variables (assuming you're working in one dimension)

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sup_x|f_\epsilon|\leq\sup_x|f(x)|\int\frac1\epsilon\phi(\frac y\epsilon)dy=\sup_x|f(x)|\int\phi(y) dy=\sup_x|f(x)|$$ where I'm assuming $\phi$ is positive, has integral 1, and we are in 1 dimension. For the others, the only additional thing to notice is that we can commute the convolution so that the derivative falls on the mollifier. $$\sup_x|f^{(n)}(x)|=\sup_x|\int f(y)\frac1{\epsilon^{1+n}}\phi^{(n)}(\frac{x-y}\epsilon)dy|\leq\sup_x|f(x)|\frac1{\epsilon^n}\int|\phi^{(n)}(y)|dy$$
which is the best possible bound.

Comment: thats exactly what I thought, thank you for the elegance in how you wrote it out, how much does the fact that $f \in L^{2}$ does this change the result?

Comment: @Landbus You can do something similar in $L^2$ but the power of $\epsilon$ will change. By Young's inequality, you can estimate the convolution by the $L^2$ norm of $\phi$ times the $L^2$ norm of $f$. Use the fact that $\|\phi(y/\epsilon)\|_{L^2}=\epsilon^{n/2}\|\phi\|_{L^2}$.